# YQL , get content inside Open Table

Tags: yql

I try to get text content inside execute script of open table...
My query is like :

```
var q = y.query('select * from html where url="http://awebpage.html" and xpath="/html/body/div/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/div/div[2]/center/div[3]//text()"');
y.log(q.results);
```

This work fine and i can see in log of console the text of the content. But i don't know how i can return this!!
if i try

```
response.object = {'test': q.results } };
```

don't work.... i try to write :

```
response.object = {'test': q.results.toXMLString() } };
```

but it return something like : `{ 'test' : '<result> bla bla bla bla </result>' }`

How can i get only the content of result?!?! I need only "bla bla bla"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it looks like you know, `q.results` is an XML object.  To get the text content as a string you would first call `text()` to get an XML text object, then call `toString()` to turn it into a JavaScript string.

```
response.object = {'test': q.results.text().toString()};
```

There is also the option of simply returning an XML object of your own.

```
response.object = <test>{q.results.text()}</test>;
```